# tensorflow2.0 logistic model ouputs nan weight and bias every time

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I wonder why this logistic model outputs weight and bias nan every time. Any possibilities? (fyi / trainset : 2082 rows × 91 columns)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

features = stock_copy2.iloc[:,:-1]
target = stock_copy2.iloc[:,-1]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = \
train_test_split(features, target, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 1)

tf.random.set_seed(2020)
W = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([91, 1], mean=0.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1], mean=0.0))
```

```
# Learning Rate
learning_rate = 0.01

# Hypothesis and Prediction Function
def predict(X):
    z = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
    hypothesis = 1 / (1 + tf.exp(-z))
    return hypothesis

# Training
for i in range(2000+1):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        hypothesis = predict(x_train)
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_train*tf.math.log(hypothesis) + (1-y_train)*tf.math.log(1-hypothesis)))        
        W_grad, b_grad = tape.gradient(cost, [W, b])

        W.assign_sub(learning_rate * W_grad)
        b.assign_sub(learning_rate * b_grad)

    if i % 400 == 0:
        print(">>> #%s \n Weights: \n%s \n Bias: \n%s \n cost: %s\n" % (i, W.numpy(), b.numpy(), cost.numpy()))
```

and the output is like this except fist random wieghts and bias that I set.

```
Weights: 
[[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan] ....
```

Comment: Looks like an exploding gradient. Did you try to reduce your learning rate ?

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing with a fixed learning rate more often than not a bad idea, as it produces suboptimal convergence results in the best case, but normally causes the model to diverge. I got your code to converge (on random data) using a RMSprop optimizer, which will automatically adapt your learning rate.

You can define a keras optimizer before training like

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001, rho=0.9)
```

and then use it to apply your tape gradient:

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([W_grad, b_grad], [W,b]))
```

instead of subtracting the gradients. Please look at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers for more information on the available optimizer modules!